# Complicated WHERE condition to sort out the data

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL table which contains data on clints (say ClientId) and dates when they paid for the service and when their service starts:

```
Headings: ClientId, PurchaseDate, StartDate
Line 1: 1; 1/07/2012; 15/07/2012
Line 2: 2; 21/06/2012; 01/07/2012
Line 3: 3; 31/07/2012; 02/08/2012
Line 4: 4; 04/08/2012; 15/08/2012
Line 5: 5; 15/08/2012; 2/09/2012
```

I have created a query which select just those clients whose service started in previous month. The condition statement is the following:

```
WHERE StartDate >= DATEADD(month, -1, dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,getdate()),0)) 
and StartDate < dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,getdate())
```

Now I need a query which would also include those clients who paid for service in previous month also. I think there can be the following statement:

```
WHERE PurchaseDate >= DATEADD(month, -1, dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,getdate()),0)) 
and PurchaseDate < dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,getdate())
```

The problem is that those clients with PurchaseDate in one month and StartDate in the next month will appear in reports for both months. So as I understand there should be complicated condition of the following meaning:

```
WHERE StartDate >= DATEADD(...)
 & StartDate < DATEADD(...) 
 & (PurchaseDate >= DATEADD(...)
 & PurchaseDate < DATEADD(...) 
 & PurchaseDate happened a month earlier than StartDate
```

Please help to find the solution.

Comment: Please post the full query as-is

Comment: Can you also explain, for people who purchased in June and started in July, whether they should show up in the June report or the July report?

Comment: Why couldn't you just do a union?

Comment: Using `GetDate()` within a query is chasing a moving target, impacts performance, and may produce curious results, e.g. as the date changes.  It is almost always a better idea to capture the current date/time in a variable and then use that value as needed.  This is more important across multiple statements as in a stored procedure.  The most common reason to use `GetDate()` multiple times is when capturing the start and end times for a long running operation.

Comment: @HABO - All calls to `GETDATE()` in a single query will return the *same* value. The second part of your comment may apply, but the first does not.

Comment: `dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(month, -1,...` - I think you might be doing more work than you need to...

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean just this:

```
WHERE StartDate >= DATEADD(...) & StartDate < DATEADD(...) 
& NOT (PurchaseDate >= DATEADD(...) & PurchaseDate < DATEADD(...))
```

Added a `NOT` to *exclude* clients from this month's start totals if they purchased last month